# open mat-expansion-panel based on a date

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of material expansion tables that is getting created from an array that is retrieved from my API service. I am building the list like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
        {{roster.date}}
    </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let y of roster.events">
    <div *ngIf="y.isFlight == false"><strong>{{y['startTimeLocal']}}</strong> {{y.Subject}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="y.isFlight == true"><strong>{{y['startTimeLocal']}}</strong> {{y.Subject}} <strong>{{y['endTimeLocal']}}</strong></div>
</li> 
</ul>
```

`roster` is passed in from a parent component. Each `roster` has three elements, `date, uuid, events` and `events` is another array of specific events happening for that day.

What I would like to do is on `ngInit` open whichever panel matches the current date. My question is how can I access the `mat-expansion-panel` in the component and then open it?

What I was thinking would be to add an id atribute to each expansion panel based on the uuid, then loop through the array of rosters looking for the matching date and then open the panel. However, I'm a bit new and I'm having a hard time understand out to get and access elements in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to access the `mat-expansion-panel` from your component (it is possible with `@ViewChild`), you can simply use the `expanded` property of the `mat-expansion-panel`.

Change your component to look like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="isPanelOpen(roster.date)">
```

And in your component add a function that determines whether an expansion panel should be open for a specific date or not:

```
// Opens every panel for which the date has a "day" of 10
public isPanelOpen(date: Date): boolean {
  return date.getDate() === 10;
}
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-vgutf3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   is a stackblitz that creates a few `mat-expansion-panel`'s and then
>   opens the one which contains the current date in the header.